# How can I use Selenium Explicit Wait

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

I'm a Korean student who likes games.
Recently, I am developing a program which crawling game items using Python selenium library. However, I have a problem.

If text is exist, sell_count will be text.
Else if text isn't exist, sell_count will be 1.

I'm using explicit wait.
but it didn't work. it takes too much time.

I try to find solution by googling. but everycase can't help me

Please help me :(

If you help me, I think I'm soooooooooooooo happy.

Thank you for read this. Have a nice day :)

```
try:
    wait(driver, 1).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#tbodyItemList > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) > div > span.count > em")))
    sell_Count = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/main/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr['+str(i)+']/td[1]/div/span[3]/em').text
    sell_Count = sell_Count[1:-8]
except:
    sell_Count = "1"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeRt7.png)

Comment: So, you are trying to indicate if `sell_Count[1:-8]` content is `1` or text?

Comment: @PedroMaia Right! I'm not good at english.  Thank you for explain.

Comment: @Prophet Yes! If text is exist, sell_count will be text_value. else it will be 1. There was a problem with my code, so I corrected it.

Comment: 1 second is a pretty short timeout. I'd increase that. It'll only wait as long as needed to find the element.  If you don't actually need to wait, use find_elements and check if returned array is 0 size.

Comment: What is `i` in your xpath ? Also that's a brittle XPath, please share website URL or HTML code to give you more accurate answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for thinking about it together! It turned out that this problem went to another page before it ended in implicit_wait function other than the code I posted, which caused the exception processing to be wrong. I'm also embarrassed because there's a problem out of the blue. Be careful when you use implicit_wait, too. Once again, I will appreciate your help. Have a nice day :)

Comment: Never mix implicit and explicit waits.  There will be two competing polling loops with unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be something like the following:

```py
wait(driver, 1).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#tbodyItemList > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) > div > span.count > em")))
sell_Count = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/main/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr['+str(i)+']/td[1]/div/span[3]/em').text
content = sell_Count[1:-8]
if not content.isdigit():
    sell_Count = content
else:
    sell_Count = "1"
```